# Process password within servlet securely

Tags: java, security, servlets

I am transmitting a password through HTTP(S) to a `HttpServlet` as parameter. To get the password I am using the Servlets `getParameter(String)` method, which returns a String. But passwords should be handled with `char[]` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords).

Well, what I want to know is: How can I process a password securely within a Java Servlet? Is my solution with `getParameter(String)` the only one or are there better options?

Please keep in mind that I am NOT interested in how to transmit a password securely (I am expecting that the transmit is secure - maybe with SSL or something else).

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that I am not using the password myself (for some kind of access restrictions for my application). I am just forwarding the password (so you could say my WebApp is something like a remote control).

Comment: Very good question, but the answer is that you shouldn't be processing passwords at all. You should be using Container Managed Authentication (CMA). The only occasion you should handle a password yourself is in change-profile or change-password requests.

Comment: @EJP Oh you're completely right I just forgot the mention something from my problem domain. I am not using the password myself (for access to my webapp) I am just forwarding it like a "remote control" to windows cmd, which requires the password. I'll edit that.

Comment: Well you're stuck with the fact that `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` returns a string. But it's only referenced during the life of the request, unless you stash a reference yourself, which you shouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

If your login parameter is sent in a POST request and contained in the request content you could parse the content yourself and put the password in a char array.

You need to do this **before** any call to `request.getParameter(String)`is made since this will make the container read and parse the content. This only works if the servlet container lazily initializes its parameter map.

Answer (score 0):

"Teleporter" approach:

Have Javascript break the password into parameters of 1 character each. Reassemble directly into char array at server side.